# Two content_for the same yield renders in all the views (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, yield, content-for

I have two separate views which are outputting content for a named yield block called :icons.

When I load the two pages, I always see in the :icons block the content of the 2 views... :-(

View 1 : Projects#Index

```
<% content_for :icons do %>
    Project Icons ...
<% end %>
...
```

View 2 : Tree#Show

```
<% content_for :icons do %>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dynatree-expand-all">Expand</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dynatree-collapse-all">Collapse</a> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dynatree-transfer">Import</a> 

  <div id="viewname_selector">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => :loopview, :action => :show}, { :id => "viewname_form" ,:remote => true}) do %>
        <%= collection_select(:viewname, :id, @viewnames, :id, :name, :selected => @current_viewname_id) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the call in the application.html.erb is

```
<div id="icons">
  <%= yield :icons %>
</div>
```

When I load Projects#index, I have only the Project Icons (so it is ok).

When I load Tree#index, I have the tree icons AND the project icons ...

What Am I doing wrong ? How to get only the tree icons in the tree view ?

Edit : Complete source of tree#index

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<title>Dynatree View <%= sicadea %></title>
<%= javascript_include_tag "leanModal/jquery.leanModal.min" %>  

<%#   For the dynatree  %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "dynatree/skin/ui.dynatree.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "dynatree/skin/ui.dynatree.custom.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "cookie/jquery.cookie.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "dynatree/jquery.dynatree-1.2.4.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "contextMenu/jquery.contextMenu.css" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "contextMenu/jquery.contextMenu-custom.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "contextMenu/jquery.ui.position.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "dynatree.js" %>

<%# for the poin'ts table %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "loopview.css" %>
<% end %>

<% content_for :icons do %>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dynatree-expand-all">Expand</a>  |
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dynatree-collapse-all">Collapse</a>  |
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dynatree-transfer">Import</a> |

<div id="viewname_selector">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => :loopview, :action => :show}, { :id => "viewname_form" ,:remote => true}) do %>
        <%= collection_select(:viewname, :id, @viewnames, :id, :name, :selected => @current_viewname_id) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>



<div id="leftpanel">
<!-- Leftpanel Context menus -->
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="rename"><a href="#rename">Rename</a></li>
    <li class="new_child"><a href="#new_child">New Child</a></li>
    <li class="copy"><a href="#copy">Copy</a></li>
    <li class="paste"><a href="#paste">Paste</a></li>
    <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="ProjectMenu" class="contextMenu">
    <li class="new_child"><a href="#new_child">New Child</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Leftpanel Tree title -->
<div id='dynatree-title' data-project-id='<%= current_project.id %>'>
    <span></span><%= current_project.name %>
</div>

<!-- Leftpanel Dynatree -->
<%= render_project_tree(current_project, "tree") %> 

<!-- Leftpanel "New Child" Form -->
<%= render :partial => "lean_new_child" %>
</div>


<!-- Right Panel -->
<div id="dynatree-details">
    <%= render :template => 'projects/show' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May I know why did you add following code in application.html.erb.

```
<div id="icons">
  <%= yield :icons %>
</div>
```

I think this only loading in your `Tree#index` page too..

Comment: No, this is for create a block chere you can add content through a content_for. It is not loading tree#index.

Comment: From where the :icons comes? from model? Can you show your full view  code for tree#index?

Comment: It comes from <% content_for :icons do %> of course. Source code of tree#index was added in the question

Comment: OK, it was tree#index who was loading the project page as default page... that was adding then the icone for the project... solved